# PowerShell throws error in folders with two spaces in their name

Tags: windows-10, powershell

In Windows 10 I just ran into following problem: When using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right-click</kbd> to start the powershell within some folder, I always get an error if the folder name contains two consecutive spaces. If you navigate to

```
"D:\foo  bar"
```

within the explorer and then use said method to open the PS you get an error and PS starts up in the folder `C:\WINDOWS\system32>`. Is there a way to fix this?

I know that usually it doesn't make sense to have two consecutive spaces in a folder name (some might argue that even one space is one too many), but that is not the question here.

EDIT: This is the rough translation (indicated by `<translation></translation>`) of the error I get (it is printed in my system language). I don't think it helps as you could easily try yourself:

```
Set-Location : <translated> The path "D:\foo bar" cannot be found because it does not exist:.
In Row:1 Character:1</translation>
+ Set-Location -literalPath 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\foo  bar'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\foo bar:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundE
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

Comment: Looks like a bug.

Comment: Reg key this is in is here: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\command.  Mine says the powershell command is "powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath '%V'".  I tried this at a PS prompt and it works.  Executing from a cmd prompt fails as well

Comment: @Ramhound Added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's escaping issue. Please see double quotes in *my* settings of `HKCR\Directory\shell` registry subkey for running PowerShell:

```
==> reg query "HKCR\Directory\shell\PowerShell" /S

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\PowerShell
    (Default)    REG_SZ    PowerShell here

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\PowerShell\command
    (Default)    REG_SZ    powershell.exe -noexit  -command Set-Location '"%V"'
```

and for running PowerShell as administrator:

```
==> reg query "HKCR\Directory\shell\runasPowerShell" /S

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runasPowerShell
    HasLUAShield    REG_SZ
    (Default)    REG_SZ    PowerShell here as administrator

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runasPowerShell\command
    (Default)    REG_SZ    Powershell Start-Process PowerShell -verb runas -ArgumentList
'-noexit', 'Push-Location -literalPath ''""""%V""""'''
```

You could modify above settings for the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\backg‌​round\shell` easy.

**Explanation**: `PowerShell.exe` parses its own command line **pre-tokenised** via a *Console Window Host* process `conhost.exe`. (*If runs from Windows explorer context menu* then spawns it's own instance of `conhost.exe`).

Therefore, all **consequent multiple spaces** (unescaped by double quoting) are considered to be redundant item separators and **shrunk** to the only one.

Of course, using single quotes *inside* PowerShell should mostly suffice…